# Interesting Puzzle: AngularJS app hangs on http 304

Tags: angularjs, cors

I have an app that is built using: PhoneGap + AngularJS (client) --- ExpressJS + MongoDB (server). The app is hosted on Amazon EC2 on an Ubuntu machine. The app was working totally fine, till...

On the EC2 machine I did a:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After I did this, I started getting the Cross Origin sharing error in my app (looking at the console in Chrome). In my AngularJS app, I have code like so that was throwing the error:

```
$http.get('http://amazon.ec2.foo/offers').success(function(data) { });
```

The error was:

```
XMLHttprequest doesn’t allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing on http://localhost:8000
```

So, I updated my server app like so:

```
app.all("/api/*", function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
      return next();
});
```

This seemed fine at first - I stopped getting the Cross Origin error, and I could see the response from the http request in the console. However, my app would stop responding and seemingly hang immediately after printing the response to the console - I am unable to click on any part of the web page, or open the developer console etc. The only resort is to close the tab and re-open it. Other tabs in Chrome were totally fine.

After debugging this for some more time, I figured that earlier (without those app headers), I was getting a HTTP 200 from the server, but now I'm getting an HTTP 304 (NOT MODIFIED), which it seems that Angular treats as an error.

I found that waiting on the tab for about ~2 minutes results in the web page loading up the data it received from the http request - but the web page stays unresponsive.

I've confirmed a few things to narrow this to AngularJS doing something weird on the HTTP 304:

- I'm running this on localhost with the same error - so, it has nothing to do with EC2.
- I removed mongodb to just send back some simple data - so, it has nothing to do with Mongo.
- I'm running this in Chrome as a simple server - so, I've eliminated PhoneGap to be the issue.

Has anyone seen this before / do you know what the problem may be & how I can solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the Network tab in Chrome console when this happens (filtering for only XHR requests)?

Comment: were you able to fix this error? If possible, Can you add more details?

Answer (score 0):

Angular treats a 304 status code as a failure, to catch the 304 (untested):

```
var prom = $http.get('http://amazon.ec2.foo/offers')
.catch(function(resp){
    if(resp.status !== 304){ $q.reject(resp) }
    return resp;   // response 
})
.catch(function(err){
    // handle or throw error
});

// Success responses and 304 responses are now available through the $http promise
prom.then( function(resp){ /* handle 200 and 304 response */ } );
```